# nodejs-snow-connector Not being Reliably called from Google Cloud Run Container

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, google-cloud-run

Trying to call a create/drop and then insert into a snowflake table.  Working well locally, after Uploading into Cloud Run container,  calls using the connector only delete table or no calls are made.

```
  const conn = connection.connect();
  conn.execute( {sqlText: 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.SHEETS (TS string, NAME string, DAYS string, DIET string, PAY string);'});
  setTimeout(() => {
    conn.execute({sqlText: 'INSERT INTO DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.SHEETS(TS, NAME, DAYS, DIET, PAY) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', binds: rows});
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: From the Snowflake Query History do you see any errors for the other operations when being run from the GC Run Container?

Comment: I have the standard membership.  For ACCESS_HISTORY you need enterprise+.  Query History only let's you grab the queries executed from snowsight.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the ACCESS_HISTORY of a database there is no way to check how this table was being accesssed while the script was running.  To solve this I went back further in the chain and scrubed the data so calling replace/create on the table wasn't necessary.  All the calls to the table were set up correctly and working well.  It cost me time so I regret not upgrading and getting visibiltiy on whatever was happening to escalate it.  My two cents...the upgrade is worth your sanity.